# event prevent default in ReactJS when passing events to parent

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs, preventdefault

I can't seem to get the e.preventDefault() handler to work in React on a child element, when passing the event up to the parent. here's my code

```
var CountdownTimer = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(e){
    this.props.addTime;
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  needMoreTime: function(){
    if(this.props.seconds_left < 10){
      return (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" 
        disabled={this.props.seconds_left > 10} 
        onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Need More Time?
        </button>
      )
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div style={{margin:"20px"}}>
        {this.needMoreTime()}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var ReviewForm = React.createClass({
  addSixtySeconds: function(){
    return this.setState({time: this.state.time + 60});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReviewTextBox seconds_left={this.state.time}/>
        <CountdownTimer seconds_left={this.state.time} addTime={this.addSixtySeconds}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

When I take out the e.preventDefault() handler, the code works fine but the button gets submitted. When add in the e.preventDefault(), the code doesn't work. How can I get this button to not submit?

Comment: What is `this.props.addTime;`? It neither set value (though you can't as its prop), nor being called. If it is a function from parent, you should called it like  `this.props.addTime();`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems in

```
handleClick: function(e){
    this.props.addTime;
    e.preventDefault();
},
```

You want to do something, but `this.props.addTime;` would not do anything if its a function, as you didn't call it.

You should use `this.props.addTime();` to call it if its a function.

The logic in

```
needMoreTime: function(){
    if(this.props.seconds_left < 10){
        return (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" 
          disabled={this.props.seconds_left > 10} 
          onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Need More Time?
        </button>
        )
    }
},
```

Seems strange, as will show value only if `this.props.seconds_left < 10`, the disabled of that button will never be true as its condition is `this.props.seconds_left > 10`, which means it will only be disabled when its not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that I'm working with native events instead of the synthetic ones of the ReactJS universe. You can do this easily wrapping the link, button or whatever includes a native behaviour that you want to properly handle, with this component that provides the library called React Native Listener.

First, install:

```
npm install --save react-native-listener
```

Then, import it:

```
var NativeListener = require('react-native-listener');
```

And wrap your button. You will see that your preventDefault works as you expect then :D

```
return (
<NativeListener onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
    <button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={this.props.seconds_left > 10}>
        Need More Time?
    </button>
</NativeListener>
)
```